# How to extract image using HSI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I have problem to extract image using HSI, and the problem is on hue.

I have tried to cropping my image and extract to grayscale, but I still have problem on HSI

```
private void rGBToHSIToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
        Bitmap org = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image.Clone(); //ghi anh da open gan vao bien org, ghi vao bo nho

    Bitmap output1 = new Bitmap(org.Width, org.Height);
    //dua ra anh ouput voi kich thuoc tuong tu anh da nhap la org

    for (Byte y = 0; y < output1.Height; y++)
    //thuc hien lap cho y chay tu o den chieu cao anh
    {
        for (Byte x = 0; x < output1.Width; x++)
        //thuc hien lap cho x chay tu 0 den chieu rong
        {
            Color c = org.GetPixel(x, y);
            Double h=0;

            Byte r = Convert.ToByte(c.R/(c.R + c.G + c.B));
            Byte g = Convert.ToByte(c.G / (c.R + c.G + c.B));
            Byte b = Convert.ToByte(c.B / (c.R + c.G + c.B));

            Byte s = Convert.ToByte(1 - 3 * Math.Min(r, Math.Min(g, b)));
            Byte k = Convert.ToByte((c.R + c.G + c.B) / (3 * 255));
            if (b<=g)
            {
              h = Convert.ToDouble((Math.Round((1 / Math.Cos((0.5 * (2 * r - g - b)) / (Math.Sqrt(((r - g) * (r - g) + (r - b) * (g - b)))))))));
            }
            else
            {
                h = Convert.ToDouble((Math.Round((2 * 3.14 - 1 / Math.Cos((0.5 * (2 * r - g - b)) / (Math.Sqrt(((r - g) * (r - g) + (r - b) * (g - b)))))))));
            }

            Byte s1 = Convert.ToByte((s * 100));
            Byte k1 = Convert.ToByte((k * 255));
             Byte h1 = Convert.ToByte(((h * 180 / 3.14)));

            output1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(h1, s1, k1));

        }
```

I want to solve the hue problem on my code, and the result can extract image to HSI image

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to extract the HSI values, or create an image with given HSI values?

You use

```
output1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(h1, s1, k1));
```

but h1, s1 and k1 are hsi values and not rgb, which FromArgb needs. This might be the problem.